# I want the options menu when the menu button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I want the options menu with icons from the api level 11 when the menu button is clicked.If it is not possible after api level 10 then please suggest me how can I do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There already are many solutions on internet, you could go through any tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The options menu is deprecated as of API 11; use the action bar or a navigation drawer instead. See: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html